# How to join two diffrent tables in php PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with this content:

```
Table users:

id                       1
username                 demoUser
pwd                      123
uid                      ghuyd3t2fgaggascxucxtu767fjc1g1e

Table all_product:

id                       1
p_name                   demoNmae
price                    demo
product_id               ghuyd3t2fgaggascxucxtu767fjc1g1e
```

I want to join them and fetch data, this is the code I'm using:

```
$uid = $_GET['pid'];

$query = "SELECT users.*, all_product.* FROM users tableUsers JOIN all_product tableProduct ON tableUsers.uid = tableProduct.product_id WHERE tableProduct.product_id = tableUsers.$uid";

$statement = $con->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row){
  echo $row['id'];
  echo $row['username'];
  echo $row['p_name'];
}
```

But I got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'users'' in /Applications/AMPPS/www/AppenceMedia/fetch_user.php:22 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/AMPPS/www/AppenceMedia/fetch_user.php(22): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/AMPPS/www/AppenceMedia/fetch_user.php on line 22

Answer (score 1):

You're using the alias of table but in select you're using the name of table.. that gives you the error.

Also in where condition bind the parameter

Try this code:

```
    $uid = $_GET['pid'];

    $query = "SELECT tableUsers.*, tableProduct.* FROM users tableUsers JOIN all_product tableProduct ON tableUsers.uid = tableProduct.product_id WHERE tableProduct.product_id = :product_id";

    $statement = $con->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindParam(':product_id', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    foreach($result as $row){
      echo $row['id'];
      echo $row['username'];
      echo $row['p_name'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have really a table named  users and If you are using  table alias the try use these in everywhere

```
$query = "SELECT tableUsers.*, tableProduct.* 
FROM users tableUsers 
JOIN all_product tableProduct ON tableUsers.uid = tableProduct.product_id 
WHERE tableProduct.product_id = tableUsers.$uid";
```

anyway  you should not use php var in sql  .. you are at risk for sqlijection  .. try take a look at prepared  statement and binding param

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is a bit wrong. You should do it like:

```
table_name as table_alias
```

So in your case:

```
$query = "SELECT users.*, tableProduct.* FROM tableUsers  as users JOIN all_product as tableProduct ON tableUsers.uid = tableProduct.product_id WHERE tableProduct.product_id = tableUsers.$uid";
```

br